# Spark-Cassandra connector error when one node is down

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm running test Cassandra cluster with 2 nodes and `replication_factor:2`. I'm aware that consistency is not on point but I'm trying to test something else currently.

While I'm trying to connect on Cassandra cluster with Spark (1.6.0v) and when one Node is down, I'm getting this error in log ->

[image]

[EDIT]
Here is the whole set of one error like @massg was asking.

```
16/12/01 16:16:23 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
16/12/01 16:16:23 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host   192.168.56.102/192.168.56.102:9042 added
16/12/01 16:16:23 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host    192.168.56.101/192.168.56.101:9042 added
16/12/01 16:16:23 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
16/12/01 16:16:28 WARN Session: Error creating pool to 192.168.56.102/192.168.56.102:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ConnectionException:    [192.168.56.102/192.168.56.102] Pool was closed during initialization
at    com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool$2.onSuccess(HostConnectionPool.java:149)
at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool$2.onSuccess(HostConnectionPool.java:135)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1181)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CombinedFuture.setOneValue(Futures.java:1626)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CombinedFuture.access$400(Futures.java:1470)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CombinedFuture$2.run(Futures.java:1548)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$FallbackFuture$1$1.onSuccess(Futures.java:475)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1181)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFuture.addListener(Futures.java:102)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1184)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$FallbackFuture$1.onFailure(Futures.java:472)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1172)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$FallbackFuture$1$1.onFailure(Futures.java:483)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1172)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.add(ExecutionList.java:101)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:170)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1184)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$FallbackFuture$1.onFailure(Futures.java:472)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1172)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:857)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.setException(SettableFuture.java:68)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:157)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$1.operationComplete(Connection.java:140)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:603)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:563)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:424)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:222)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there anyway to make some exception in spark/scala to see if one of node is not accessbile to ignore the same and look up for its replica like Cassandra is doing but wihtout any errors in log?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you copy the exception as formatted text in the question? Images are not searchable, which lowers the value of the question as future reference for others.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking: I suppose that the program is running correctly? Do you want to suppress the exception from the logs?

Comment: Yeah, program is working correctly but the thing I want is to remove anerror message from log or suppress it. Is there any method in connector or in spark where he will bypass an error if one node is down? Is it now more clear?

Comment: You could change the log level to `error`. This is only a `warning`. Not sure why you want this, though. It indicates an actual, but recoverable failure.

Comment: If spark assumes that one node is down I want that he just skip that node and search for next replica where data is. Cassandra is actually doing that job but Spark is returning a feedback that node is down and that he is trying to reach the node which is down. I want -> if he assumes that node si down, than leave it and search replica and stop ping that node as and returning feedback about `Error creating pool` which could maybe slow down whole process.

Comment: If you look at the exception stack, the warning comes from `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions` which is the Java Driver for Cassandra by DataStax. So, it's the driver layer that's handling the connection, not spark.

Comment: So is it possible to manage `poolingOptions` and sessions in Spark/Scala because I haven't see a example yet?

Comment: the `connectionPool` is managed by the Spark-Cassandra connector. See [configuration reference](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md)